# Configuring iptables to block all ports with three exceptions

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

I have been struggling with iptables in Linux to get the right configuration. Basically, I am trying to set rules that accomplish the following goals:

Incoming traffic that is part of an established TCP session is allowed

Incoming traffic on the normal WWW and SSH ports is allowed

All other TCP ports are blocked

For whatever reason, only the SSH port seems to work properly.

Answer (score 3):

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack -j ACCEPT  --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport -m state --state NEW -j DROP ! --dports 22,80
```

The last rules should be:

```
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

If you have multiple network cards in your PC you may wish to specify which ones it will affect, otherwise it will affect ALL of them.

Depending on how the rest of your firewall is setup you may need to duplicate these rules in the FORWARD chain.

These rules must be at, or near the top of the rules the INPUT/FORWARD chains are rules preceding it will override these rules.

Unless you are running a web server port 80 isn't even necessary.

Comment: And port 22 should be replaced by a non-standard port to deter script kiddies.